# Why must "other" be used in "Iron is more useful than any other metal"?

Tags: comparative

> When two objects are compared with each other, the latter term of comparison must exclude the former, as in "Iron is more useful than any other metal". If we say "Iron is more useful than any metal", that is the same thing as saying "Iron is more useful than iron", since iron is itself a metal.

I do not understand this. Please, can someone explain what it means?

Comment: This properly belongs on ELL, and in fact I see it's a duplicate of their Q85071, so it will be linked to that one. (If I put a link here the comment will probably disappear on migration).

Comment: Don't get too hung up on completely ***literal*** interpretation. There are *many, **many*** written instances of [***better than anyone in the world***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22better+than+anyone+in+the+world%22) in Google Books (and doubtless even more for *better than **anything** in the world*). But in nearly every case, the person or thing being compared will ***also*** be "in the world". Nobody really cares that much whether the word ***else*** in included in such contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Iron is more useful than **any metal.**

Put another way, this means

> Iron is more useful than **iron.**  This is because **any metal** could mean **iron** as well. And this leads to an absurdity.

> Iron is more useful than **any other metal.**

The phrase **any other metal** excludes *iron* from the list of metals (for the purpose of comparison.) And thus  this version makes sense.